# iOS 11 share-sheet not including Messages option

Tags: ios

Upgraded to iOS 11 and noticed that my share-sheet no longer includes the option to share in Messages. Has anyone experienced this and know how to get the functionality back?

I’ve confirmed it hasn’t been disabled in the “more” options

This seems to be happening in most 3rd party applications and from the home screen when using “Share App” feature via 3-D touch

[image: no share sheet]
[image: not available under more options]

Comment: Just making sure–are you signed in to iCloud?

Comment: I am, but don’t think that should matter. Messages still handles SMS text messages which supports iTunes URLs and photos

Comment: Hm, yeah. I don't know, then. Does it still work in, say, the Photos app but just not in third-party apps, or does it not work in _any_ app?

Comment: Doesn’t work in *any* app

Comment: OK, weird. Does rebooting help? (Just rebooting fixes _all sorts_ of wacky problems!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug is now resolved in iOS 11.1

Answer (score 0):

I’d try installing the iOS 11.01 update via Settings > General > Software Update.

For more information, refer to: [iOS 11.0.1: What’s New Or Changed?](http://www.redmondpie.com/ios-11.0.1-release-notes-changelog-and-other-changes-for-iphone-and-ipad/)

Comment: Updated to 11.0.1 and still not working

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MobileIron installed? I do and experienced the same issue. I read that was causing it, so I uninstalled and Messages came back. Then I reinstalled MobileIron and it went away again. I downgraded to iOS 10.3 as Apple Support couldn't help easily.

I haven't tried since iOS 11.0.2 came out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a mobile device management certificate installed and it was causing this.  Removing it solved the issue.  Found the answer via https://ios.gadgethacks.com/how-to/get-back-missing-message-icon-ios-11s-share-sheet-0180193/